# How to display empty rows and columns in matrix SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, mdx, olap

I have a report that groups by week on column and row on productID and productType and the valus as productValue.

﻿

I need to display all week and productType even where the data does not exist.

Here is my mdx query

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
        [Measures].[Distributor Sale Out], 
        [Measures].[Distributor Sale Out Trend]
}
ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY { 
          ([Date].[Calendar Week].[Calendar Week].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [Distributors].[Distributor].[Distributor].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [Distributors].[DistributorID].[DistributorID].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [Distributors].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [Product].[SKU].[SKU].ALLMEMBERS *
           [Product].[Product].[Product].ALLMEMBERS *
           [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [SaleType].[SaleType].[Sale Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [SaleType].[Sale Type Id].[Sale Type Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } 

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
           FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DistributorsDistributorID, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
                 FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DateCalendarYear, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
                         FROM [EFES SCM]
            ))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the two instances of `NON EMPTY` you have in your `mdx` and see what happens?

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Distributor Sale Out]
   ,[Measures].[Distributor Sale Out Trend]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
      [Date].[Calendar Week].[Calendar Week].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Distributors].[Distributor].[Distributor].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Distributors].[DistributorID].[DistributorID].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Distributors].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Product].[SKU].[SKU].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Product].[Product].[Product].ALLMEMBERS*
      [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS*
      [SaleType].[SaleType].[Sale Type].ALLMEMBERS*
      [SaleType].[Sale Type Id].[Sale Type Id].ALLMEMBERS
  }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    (@DistributorsDistributorID
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      (@DateCalendarYear
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM [EFES SCM]
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks,when i remove NonEmpty, the result is wright, but it take a lot of time. Report is generated about 4 minutes

Comment: @Nastya the report running slow is another issue. How many rows does it return to the report? The cross-join you have on rows is very large, can we apply NonEmpty to some of the hierarchies in the cross-join or do you need to see every empty cell?

Comment: a lot of rows ) i apply nonempty only for hierarchies i need. In query designer query work quickly, but in report slowly

Comment: I suspect rendering the data in the report takes time -  if you're trying to return 100,000 rows then it will be slow in the report!